# How can I pevent Gridview.DataBind when a commandField is pressed

Tags: asp.net, search, gridview, edit, commandfield

I have a gridview included "Edit CommandFields Update and Cancel" at the last column of my gridview. Also, I have  a search button above my Gridview and everything works properly together. When I am searching for a particular Column the "sqlDataSource" of my Gridview is changing respectively on the query and displays the results.

However, the Edit/Update/Cancel command field buttons refresh the whole Gridview and I am loosing the selected editable row derived from the search results.

How can I prevent grdiview Databing when I click the Edit Command Field ?

Any advice would be appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the famous is Page.IsPostback check.In vb.net you will have to do some thing like this

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack
->your binding code goes here
End if
```

C#

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{

  ->your binding code goes here

}
```

This way your results are not lost when the page reloads.